# ASP Login authentication

Tags: asp.net

I have a Login page which include 2 `text-boxes` and one `button`.

when I login the page goes (for example) to my `Home.aspx` page.

when I `Back the browser` to previous page it goes back to my `Login` page AND if I click the `Forward browser` arrow button it goes to my `Home` page again.

the problem is I user clock back to my `Login` Page AND wants to Click `Forward`, the page will not let user to go to home page again and ask to enter `Username` and `Password` again

Comment: Are you using `Forms Authentication`? How you are processing the authentication?

Comment: this is my authentication
<forms defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx">

Comment: <authorization>
   <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>

Answer (score 0):

After user log in you have to save some data in **SESSION** for authentication.

You can find information about session from this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: already I have session
if session = admin goes to admin page and if session = user it goes to user page.
what should I do now ?

Comment: clean session when you back to login page

Comment: In normal cases .If you already log in it is better to have such button or page when you go there it will clear your session and redirects you Login page.This is user friendly.

But if you want when user goes back to Login page you want him re enter username and password just clear session detail with

Clear.Session ()

in code behind .